# scikit-learn:ImportError: cannot import name atleast2d_or_csr

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I am working with ELM(extreme learning machine) in python, I came into this problem:ImportError: cannot import name atleast2d_or_csr.The details of error is listed as follows:

```
C:\Users\sherlock\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
"This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-50-dad0703e9d35>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/sherlock/Desktop/Ensemble Learnig/Python-ELM-master
/plot_elm_comparison.py', wdir='C:/Users/sherlock/Desktop/EnsembleLearnig
/Python-ELM-master')

File "C:\Users\sherlock\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils
\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\sherlock\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils  
\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "C:/Users/sherlock/Desktop/Ensemble Learnig/Python-ELM-master 
/plot_elm_comparison.py", line 75, in <module>
from elm import ELMClassifier

File "elm.py", line 34, in <module>
from random_hidden_layer import SimpleRandomHiddenLayer

File "random_hidden_layer.py", line 27, in <module>
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state, atleast2d_or_csr

ImportError: cannot import name atleast2d_or_csr
```

The concerned statement may be:

```
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state, atleast2d_or_csr
```

Comment: You might want to check this out : https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4457

Answer (score 3):

**Replace the following**:

```
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state, atleast2d_or_csr
```

---

**with this**:

```
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state, check_array
```

---

**Reference**: [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6587)